# How do you conditionally apply multiple classes to a single Material UI classes prop

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material UI Drawer and would like to apply a class called "paperStyle" to the classes prop with the rule name "paper" and then conditionally apply an additional class called "specialPaperStyle" if the user is of a particular type. But I haven't been able to apply two classes to the paper rule, let alone apply it conditionally and wondered if anyone knew what to do?

Here are the key parts of my code:

### Styles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paperStyle: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    boxShadow: 'inset 0 0.3rem 1.5rem rgba(0,0,0,0.19)',
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
      minHeight: '100%',
      position: 'relative',
    }, 
  },
  specialPaperStyle:{ 
    backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to bottom right, #27133f, transparent)',
},
}));
```

### Material UI drawer

```
<Drawer
   classes={{
     paper: classes.paper,
   }}
 >
      Contents of drawer
</Drawer>
```

The above works in that my paperStyle class is being applied, but how do I conditionally apply the specialPaperStyle class to paper? For example:

### Doesn't work!

```
<Drawer
   classes={{
     paper: {`${classes.paperStyle isSpecial && $classes.specialPaperStyle}`},
   }}
 >
      Contents of drawer
</Drawer>
```

Many thanks,

Katie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

material-ui comes with a handy package [clsx](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx) that makes easier to add classes based on specific conditions. You can pass several class arguments, or also objects that will display the class key if the given value is truthy:

```
import clsx from 'clsx';

<Drawer
   classes={{
     paper: {clsx(classes.paperStyle, {[classes.specialPaperStyle]: isSpecial})},
   }}
 >
      Contents of drawer
</Drawer>
```

[docs](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#whats-the-clsx-dependency-for) about clsx on material-ui

Comment: Great answer thank you! The only reason I didn't give it the tick was because my colleague prefers not to use packages where possible, but I think this is a super helpful answer :)

Comment: You are welcome! I answered with this package because this already comes with material-ui, you don't have to install it, and it's much cleaner syntax to write classes.

Comment: @Katie7 Please revote this answer and use answer without package.

Comment: I've re-voted this as the correct answer, but both are good! :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

UPDATED

```
<Drawer
   classes={{
     paper: {`${classes.paperStyle} ${isSpecial ? classes.specialPaperStyle : ''}`},
   }}
 >
      Contents of drawer
</Drawer>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't reply to your answer! I forgot I'd asked it but returned to ask the same question today. Thanks so much! This worked for me except that I had to remove the curly brackets from around the content literal.